# iPhone need to get a CGContextRef context reference for a sub view

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I'm using an IBoutlet to get a reference to a Sub-View I added to the main View in the interface builder but since this won't give me access to drawRect: I won't be able to get a context to draw on. Is there anyway I can still get the graphics context so I can draw on the sub view? How would I go about this?

Comment: Views don't have contexts. A context is created for them when `-drawRect:` is called, but outside of the confines of `-drawRect:` no context exists.

Answer (score 3):

You can't draw like that; you have to draw in response to a `drawRect` call, not at any time as some frameworks allow.

The correct way to do it is: create a UIView subclass in Xcode. Switch to Interface Builder, select your subview, and change its "Class Identity" (under "Tools > Identity Inspector") to the name of your new subclass.

Then in your subclass, you can implement `drawRect`.

Answer (score 2):

Technically there is a means to for one object to become the drawing delegate of another via the view.layer.delegate route. One can construct a delegate to implement

- (void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx

This gives you the ability to reuse drawing instructions should it become necessary. But it can be tedious to read and understand for another programmer. Most would avoid it unless it eliminates code duplication.

Answer (score 0):

You should never be drawing in another view, not even a subview. The subview should draw itself, and it has access to its own graphics context. You cannot get access to another view's context; they are handled by the framework and are set up before calling `-drawRect:` for the appropriate view.